# JavaScript Function Access this from calling Element

Tags: javascript, reference, scope, this

I have a function that I want to execute relevant to the calling elements but I can't seem to the pass it as itself as a reference to the function I want to execute.

In short, this works

```
<div style="background-color:#444444">
    <button onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';">close</button>
</div>
```

And this does not

```
<script>
   function close() { this.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; }
</script>

<div style="background-color:#444444">
    <button onclick="close()">close</button>
</div>
```

Why is this and is there a way around it?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", close)`

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I'm an idiot

It seems I can simply pass the Element to the function with the this keyword

```
<script>
    function close(object) { object.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; }
</script>

<div style="background-color:#444444">
    <button onclick="close(this)">close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the `close()` function, `this` is the `window` object.

Try passing the element as argument:

```
<script>
    function close(btn) { btn.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; }
</script>

<div style="background-color:#444444">
    <button onclick="close(this)">close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, 'this' isn't pointing to the same object in the function as it is in the in-line code.  You could pass 'this' in the function call, as in:

```
<script>
   function close(whichObj) { whichObj.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; }
</script>

<div style="background-color:#444444">
    <button onclick="close(this)">close</button>
```

HTH,
Jim